# How do I get my background image to not repeat?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to get the image to display as one unified image in the background. What am I doing wrong? thanks.

```
.content{
    background-color: gray;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:url(cropped.jpg);
    background-repeat: no repeat; 
}
```

Comment: You have a typo there, missing a dash in `no-repeat`

Comment: Wow...I've seen very clever CSS solutions getting 1 upvote, and here a typo gets 5 ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `no repeat` to `no-repeat`, that should do the trick.